# Is my credit score too low? type of questions

Tags: discussion, faq

The specific question is: 
[Is my credit score of 766 lower than it should be?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/is-my-credit-score-of-766-lower-than-it-should-be)

Personally, I think this question is subjective as it depends on a variety of things.  I myself think that is a decent score for someone fresh out of college, but I can easily see someone disagreeing with that assessment.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a question title change might make this question better.

I can't think of quite the perfect wording, but the poster seems to be asking if they calculated their Fico score correctly.   Namely, does their credit history support a score of 766.

Maybe:

- Is my credit score accurately reflecting my credit history?
- Are the credit bureaus calculating my score correctly?

Or maybe this is more of what the poster means:

- Shouldn't my credit score be higher than 766 given my payment history?

Those are questions that maybe a loan officer or bank employee who sees credit scores on a regular basis may be able to answer objectively.

Comment: Good point, based on the accepted answer it seems that your interpretation is correct.